# Hide nested fields with "name" in $project mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is the document available that needs to be projected by hiding all the "name" fields in the document. Not sure if we have any specific way in mongo aggregation framework to search for all the nested fields with name - "name" and hide it. Please suggest

```
   "group1":{
      "field1":{
         "name":"a"
      },
      "field2":{
         "data":{
            "name":"b"
         }
      },
      "group2":{
         "field2":{
            "name":"a"
         },
         "field3":{
            "data":{
               "name":"b"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Expected output:

```
    {
      group1: {
        field1: {
    
        }, "field2": {
           "data": {
           }
        },
      
      "group2": {
        "field2": {
        }, "field3": {
           "data": {
           }
        }
      }
    } 
    }
```

Comment: Dynamic level of nesting is considered an anti-pattern and introduces unnecessary complexity to queries. There is no generic way to achieve what you want. Consider refactoring your schema.

Comment: @ray we have to merge a few documents to build a parent json but we need to ignore a few fields from it